# How would I call a constructor defined in C# from MSBuild?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I'm trying to convert this C# code to run in MSBuild:

```
var uri = new Uri(s1);

var result = uri.MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(s2)).ToString();
```

I'm not quite sure how you would call the `Uri` constructor from MSBuild, though. Here is what I have so far:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- <FirstUri>???</FirstUri>
         <SecondUri>???</SecondUri> -->
    <RelativeUri>$(FirstUri.MakeRelativeUri($(SecondUri)))</RelativeUri>
    <AsString>$(RelativeUri.ToString())</RelativeUri>
</PropertyGroup>
```

As you can see, I've commented out the `FirstUri` and `SecondUri` snippets because I couldn't figure out how to get them to work. I've tried `new Uri($(FirstString))`, but that just caused it to be subsituted with the literal value of s1 (e.g. `"new Uri(C:\Users)"`).

How do I get this to work? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

---

**edit:** Well, it looks like it's not possible from straight MSBuild. I've accepted Mark Arnott's answer of creating a custom MSBuild task, although I don't think I'll be doing this by myself.

Perhaps if you were running on Windows-only clients, you could do something like this:

```
<Exec Command="powershell '(New-Object [System.Uri] ...'" />
```

I'm a bit hesitant to start a whole new process just to create relative paths though, so that's a bit of a dealbreaker.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling people lazy if you want an answer from them. YOU are supposed to provide the code needed for someone to answer the question, not a link for the code.

Comment: @MiguelAlexandre I'm sorry, I was just trying to be humorous. I've edited my post accordingly, apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your goal is, but if you really need MSBuild to run some C# code, you need to use inline tasks.
See [MSDN's Walkthrough: Creating an Inline Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723643.aspx)

Most of the time MSBuild runs pre-compiled tasks and command line utilities.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would do this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <FirstUri>$([System.Uri]::new($(FirstString)))</FirstUri>
    <SecondUri>$([System.Uri]::new($(SecondString)))</SecondUri>
    <RelativeUri>$(FirstUri.MakeRelativeUri($(SecondUri)))</RelativeUri>
    <AsString>$(RelativeUri.ToString())</AsString>
</PropertyGroup>
```

However, `System.Uri` is not an available type in MSBuild. The [MSBuild Property Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx) contains a list of types available, but I found it is not inclusive of everything. I have found the other types like `System.Version` and constructors (not just static functions) available.